# How to seek forward a song from bluetooth on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

I am currently working on an iPhone App, where I need a `UISlider` to change to the value I get from the Bluetooth. Receiving the Data works just fine, but when it comes to changing the Slider, nothing works.

[image: screenshot]

```
-(IBAction)progressEnd
{
    self.panningProgress = NO;

    if(self.songPlayer)
    {
        CMTime t = CMTimeMake(self.progressSlider.value, 1);
        self.trackCurrentTimer.text = [self stringFromTime:t.value];
        [self.songPlayer seekToTime:t];
    }
    else if([TDAudioPlayer sharedAudioPlayer].state == TDAudioPlayerStatePlaying)
    {
        float t1 = self.progressSlider.value;
        float t2 = [[TDAudioPlayer sharedAudioPlayer] getPlayerTime];

        if(t1<=t2)
        {  
            self.progressSlider.value = t1;
            self.trackCurrentTimer.text = [self stringFromTime:t1];
            [[TDAudioPlayer sharedAudioPlayer] internalSeekToTime:t1];
        }
    }  
}
- (IBAction)progressChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.panningProgress = YES;
    self.trackCurrentTimer.text = [self stringFromTime:sender.value];
}
```

Comment: You needed to use the format code sample button when pasting the code - have done that for you. You should also explain more clearly what  you mean by "nothing works". What actually happens? Press the edit button to add more explanation.